# Flask. Получение файлов

Tags: python, html, flask

Создаю сайт на котором редакторы могут загружать статьи. Столкнулся с проблемой при загрузке редактором файлов в пост.

Когда я получаю данные таким способом images = request.files.getlist('images'), то на выходе я получаю отсортированный по названиям список загруженных редактором файлов.
[<FileStorage: 'test1.jpg' ('image/jpeg')>, <FileStorage: 'test2.jpg' ('image/jpeg')>, <FileStorage: 'test3.jpg' ('image/jpeg')>, <FileStorage: 'test4.jpg' ('image/jpeg')>]

Мне необходимо избежать сортировки, так как важно сохранить очередность загрузки редактором файлов, так как это напрямую влияет на логику поста. Конечно, можно заставить редакторов переименовывать файлы, но такое решение мне не подходит

Comment: Каким образом редакторы задают очерёдность загрузки? Задают ли они её вообще?

Comment: Когда нажимает кнопку "Добавить файлы" то открывается обычное меню выбора файлов с компьютера, там при добавлении нескольких файлов в строке отображаются названия добавленных файлов в таком виде: "test4.jpg" "test1.jpg" "test2.jpg" "test3.jpg", мне нужно чтоб они передались в такой же последовательности https://imgur.com/a/Tq5XqPp